# Display Getway error message to use Magento

Tags: php, magento

```
<?php class Swetin_Mygateway_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    // The redirect action is triggered when someone places an order
    public function redirectAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','swetin',array('template' => 'swetin/redirect.phtml'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


    public function responseAction() {

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {


            $validated = false;

            // Generally sent by gateway
            $status_codes = $this->getRequest()->getPost('gtpay_tranx_status_code');
            $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('gtpay_tranx_id');
            //$orderId = "";
            $orderStatMsg = $this->getRequest()->getPost('gtpay_tranx_status_msg');

            //echo $status_codes;

            if($status_codes == "00" ){ $validated = true; }

            //$orderId = $requesting['gtpay_tranx_id']; 

            if($validated) {
                // Payment was successful, so update the order's state, send order email and move to the success page
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
                $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Payment authorized!');

                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                $order->setEmailSent(true);

                $order->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();

                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
            }
            else {
                // There is a problem in the response we got
                $this->cancelAction($orderStatMsg);
                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure'=>true));
            }
        }
        else
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('');
    }

    // The cancel action is triggered when an order is to be cancelled
    public function cancelAction($orderStatMsg) {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
            if($order->getId()) {

                        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($orderStatMsg);
                session_write_close();

                // Flag the order as 'cancelled' and save it  'Card has declined the payment.'
                $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, $orderStatMsg)->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the messages from the gateways.  Is it `addSuccess`, `addError`... to collect it in the session?

instead of showing this:
AN ERROR OCCURRED IN THE PROCESS OF PAYMENT
Order #100000091

Click here to continue shopping.

i want it to show:

AN ERROR OCCURRED IN THE PROCESS OF PAYMENT
Error: Insufficient funds or what ever error message gateway returns
Order #100000091

Click here to continue shopping.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Mage::throwException()
```

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php

```
case self::RESPONSE_CODE_DECLINED:
case self::RESPONSE_CODE_ERROR:
     Mage::throwException($this->_wrapGatewayError($result->getResponseReasonText()));
default:
     Mage::throwException($defaultExceptionMessage);
```

Comment: I'm using a custom payment method not authorizenet does it still applu

Comment: And that's what's in response method

Comment: Could you add the full code, there is no `throwException` in your code above

Comment: i modified the question, please check, Thank you.